# include an HTML page in an HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a website and I want to use my dropdown menu as a separate code from any links in website.
http://www.stelianpopa.ro/photo/ancar.html 
I use the code for my menu in menu.html and I integrated on website based on this example: http://api.jquery.com/load/
The codes are loaded but most of the time the drop menu doesn't work, even if appear to be loaded, it shows only the first line and not the submenu for "photo" and "video"

Any help for that?
Basically wat I want is to have my menu as an independent file and to be loaded on any html on my website as a reference, because when I want to add something in the menu I had to do it on every single html and that's why I want to be standalone, to modify once for every html.
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Your dropdown menu does not work well to begin with. The Chrome status line overlaps the submenus

Answer (score 0):

If not already, make a html file that includes your menu (dropdown).

Then, on every page that you want to use the menu, include an [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) pointing to the html file you created for your menu.

For example:

**Menu.html**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<!-- code for menu -->

</body>
</html>
```

**Every page you want to use the menu on**

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>

<!-- content -->
<iframe src='path/to/menu.html'>Sorry, but your browser does not support iframe.</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Surely there are better options than to use an iframe. A small script can easily inject the menu onto the page

Comment: Yap, I don't want to use an iframe because my menu use some css for styling and also some java for loading.

Comment: If you don't want to use iframe, you could use a script to dynamically append the menu (as html) to your body. Like @Clint said.

Answer (score 0):

Without templating, you can use javascript to load template onto the page. I would set up a mini project for this to avoid copy-pasting, but the basics are below

In the body where you want the menu:

```
<div id="my-nav-menu"></div>
```

script:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var menu = document.getElementById('my-nav-menu');
    menu.innerHTML = 'menu html here';
});
```

**Update**

I just noticed the jquery tag, so you can use the following script instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my-nav-menu').html('menu html here');
});
```